# Using if else in django models.py

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to create an admin interface in my django models.py, such that when the status variable is selected to be completed it should ask for the various fields.

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to='EventPosters')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    STATUS = (('upcoming', 'upcoming'), ('completed', 'completed'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='upcoming')
    if status == 'completed':
        report = models.TextField()
        images_url = models.URLField()
        no_of_images = models.CharField(max_length=1, validators=[DecimalValidator])
        images_list = {}
        for i in range(int(no_of_images)):
            images_list[i] = models.ImageField(upload_to='EventImages')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Above is the class for the model that I am trying to create, I would like if the user selects the event is completed it should ask for the remaining fields in the admin panel automatically.
Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: You can't do that in the models.py, if you want to manipulate the admin, adjust the admin.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write all the fields in the model without a condition, adding the argument "blank=True"to them.
And would add a condition to templates. If the condition is triggered, additional fields appear.